# In Flutter listView is not scrollabe when I move the container( in which I have defined listView)

Tags: android, ios, flutter

This is where I am using listView

```
Widget _buildIconsContainer(Size size){
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: -size.height * 0.11,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: SettingConst.mdPadding),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SettingConst.mdPadding),
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height * 0.5,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(SettingConst.lgRadius),
                topRight: Radius.circular(SettingConst.lgRadius),
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SettingConst.smPadding),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => print("clicked"),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        StringConst.greetingImg,
                        width: size.width * 0.2,
                        height: size.width * 0.2,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      StringConst.greetingImg,
                      width: size.width * 0.2,
                      height: size.width * 0.2,
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      StringConst.greetingImg,
                      width: size.width * 0.2,
                      height: size.width * 0.2,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
              itemCount: 10,),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 15,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: SettingConst.mdPadding),
              child: CustomButton(onPressed: (){}, text: 'Save Changes', textStyle: SettingConst.subHeadingStyle(color: ColorConst.greenColor),)),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIv7i.jpg)

When I scroll by clicking on these three image the scroll doesn't happen. I guess this is happening only for those which are over the greeting container. Because when I scroll usign the below images then the scrolling works fine.

When I remove this line
`top: -size.height * 0.11`
which I declared inside the icon Container the scroll is working fine. But I want to move the container up.

Here's my full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hardcopy/screen/home.dart';
import 'package:hardcopy/widgets/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../const/color.dart';
import '../const/settings.dart';
import '../const/string.dart';
import '../provider/user_provider.dart';

class SettingScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  static const String routeName = '/setting';
  const SettingScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SettingScreen> createState() => _SettingScreenState();
}

class _SettingScreenState extends State<SettingScreen>{

  bool editText = false;
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  final TextEditingController userNameController = TextEditingController();



  toggleEdit(){
    setState(() {
      editText = !editText;
      focusNode.requestFocus();
      userNameController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: userNameController.text.length));
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    userNameController.dispose();
    focusNode.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // Getting user from the provider
    final user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).user;
    // Setting default username and PhoneNumber if username and phoneNumber not exists (ONLY FOR DEVELOPMENT)
    String userName = 'Sakshi';
    String phoneNumber = '1234567890';
    if(user.userName.isNotEmpty){
      userName = user.userName;
    }
    if(user.mobileNumber.isNotEmpty){
      phoneNumber = user.mobileNumber;
    }
    userNameController.text = userName;

    // Editing Controller for the TextField with default value of the userName
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          _buildGreeting(
            size,
            userName,
            phoneNumber,
            editText,
            toggleEdit,
            userNameController,
            focusNode,
          ),
          Expanded(child: _buildIconsContainer(size)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  PreferredSizeWidget _buildAppBar(){
    return AppBar(
      title: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, HomeScreen.routeName, (route) => false),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGreeting(
      Size size,
      String userName,
      String phoneNumber,
      bool editText,
      Function() toggleEdit,
      TextEditingController userNameController,
      FocusNode focusNode,
      ){
    return  IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: SettingConst.greetingTopPadding,
          left: SettingConst.mdPadding,
          right: SettingConst.mdPadding,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(SettingConst.lgRadius),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(SettingConst.mdPadding),
          child: Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: SettingConst.greetingImgPosition,
                child: Image.asset(
                  StringConst.greetingImg,
                  width: SettingConst.greetingImageWidth,
                  height: SettingConst.greetingImageHeight,
                ),
              ),
              if(!editText)
                Positioned(
                  top: 60,
                  right: 60,
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        toggleEdit();
                        // focusNode.requestFocus();
                        // userNameController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: userNameController.text.length));
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.white,
                        size: 16,))),
              Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: SettingConst.greetingTextPadding),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Hi, ',
                        style: SettingConst.headingStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      editText ? Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
                          child: IntrinsicWidth(
                            child: TextField(
                              focusNode: focusNode,
                              controller: userNameController,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: -10),
                                border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      width: 2.0,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ),
                              style: SettingConst.headingStyle(color: ColorConst.greenColor),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                      :
                      Text(
                        userName,
                        style: SettingConst.headingStyle(color: ColorConst.greenColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                 Text(
                   phoneNumber,
                   style: SettingConst.subHeadingStyle(),
                 ),
                  const SizedBox(height: SettingConst.greetingContainerBottomPadding),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIconsContainer(Size size){
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: -size.height * 0.11,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: SettingConst.mdPadding),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SettingConst.mdPadding),
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height * 0.5,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(SettingConst.lgRadius),
                topRight: Radius.circular(SettingConst.lgRadius),
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SettingConst.smPadding),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => print("clicked"),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        StringConst.greetingImg,
                        width: size.width * 0.2,
                        height: size.width * 0.2,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      StringConst.greetingImg,
                      width: size.width * 0.2,
                      height: size.width * 0.2,
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      StringConst.greetingImg,
                      width: size.width * 0.2,
                      height: size.width * 0.2,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
              itemCount: 10,),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 15,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: SettingConst.mdPadding),
              child: CustomButton(onPressed: (){}, text: 'Save Changes', textStyle: SettingConst.subHeadingStyle(color: ColorConst.greenColor),)),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Tell me what I am doing wrong. And How can I achieve my goal.

I want to have the view of my app as it is but just the content to be scrollable. Because if I remove the position widget from my listView then the scroll is working fine. But I don't want that.